# Bundle identifier does not have com. In my xcode project Why? How can I fix it?

Tags: xcode, bundle-identifier

Bundle identifier does not have `com.` in my XCode project.

1. Why?
2. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why-**

Normally XCode puts a nice bundle identifer. Maybe you don't have an account name to your mac or maybe while setting up your project you edited the bundle identfier.

**2. How to fix-**

Have a look at "Setting the Bundle ID" in [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html).

You can edit bundle identifier from-

[image]

My bundle identifier is `com.nikhilmanapure.avfoundationexample`.

Normal convention is web url in reversed manner and appending project name. This makes the bundle identifier unique. Your aim should be making bundle identifier unique, because that is needed when you upload app to AppStore.